# SAS Macro pulling monthly data

Tags: sas

Hello I am trying to build a macro process that allows me to pull data from the most current month to a x amount of months(historically), however it seems to only pull for one month any thoughts ?

```
%LET START_DATE = 20140731;

DATA _NULL_; 
  START_DATE = input(cat(&START_DATE),YYMMN6.); 
  FORMAT START_DATE date9.;
  MON_START_DT=put(START_DATE,date9.);
  CALL SYMPUTX('MON_START_DT',put(MON_START_DT,9.));
RUN;

%MACRO DO_FOR(NUM_OF_MONTHS);
  %DO I = 0 %TO &NUM_OF_MONTHS-1;
    DATA _NULL_;
      END_DATE=intnx('month',"&MON_START_DT"d,&I,'end');
      FORMAT END_DATE yymmdd10.;
      MON_END_DATE=put(END_DATE,yymmdd10.);
      MON_END_DATE=COMPRESS(MON_END_DATE," (-)");
      FORMAT MON_END_DATE $8.;
      CALL SYMPUTX('BATCH_ID',put(MON_END_DATE,$8.));
    RUN;


    PROC SQL;
    sysecho; 
      CREATE TABLE work.table AS
        SELECT FROM WHERE 
   /*ex This table contains months of data*/ 


  %END;
%MEND DO_FOR;

%DO_FOR(NUM_OF_MONTHS=03);
```

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Comment: Sorry Updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't `&I` have a minus sign in front of it to go backwards in time rather than forwards in time?  If you start at the current month and only go forwards you will only get one month.

```
  END_DATE=intnx('month',"&MON_START_DT"d,-&I,'end');
```